# How to join two queries to get result in single query

Tags: sql, mysql-5.5

I have two queries. From 1st one I am getting selected year and month data and from the second query I am getting the data of previous year i.e for the last year

**query1:**  `SELECT sum(a.netamount) NETAMOUNT,e.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR,YEAR(BILLDATE) AS DATEYEAR, MONTH (BILLDATE) DATEMONTH FROM syncbill a,ecustomer e WHERE a.OUTLET=e.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER  and YEAR(BILLDATE) = '2018' AND MONTH(BILLDATE) = '09' group by outlet`

**query2:** `SELECT sum(a.netamount) NETAMOUNT,e.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR,YEAR(BILLDATE) AS DATEYEAR, MONTH (BILLDATE) DATEMONTH FROM syncbill a,ecustomer e WHERE a.OUTLET=e.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER and YEAR(BILLDATE) = '2018-1' AND MONTH(BILLDATE) = '09' group by outlet`

I am using MySQL 5.5 and putting year-1 to get previous year data
like 2018-1 gives 2017.

Everything is common between these two queries except the year in query1 year is `2018` and in query2 year is `2018-1 i.e 2017`.

So I want to join both the queries so that I can get data in single run.

[image: query1 result]

[image: query2 result]

because there is no data in 2017 that's why it is showing blank, but I want to show 0 instead.

[image: This what I am trying to achieve]

I know I can get this with joins but have very limited experience in that.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Also, why have you tagged MySQL and SQL Server? These are 2 very different RDBMS. I have removed all your tags and added the SQL tag. Please edit your tags to be correct for the RDBMS you are using, and **only** the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(a.netamount) NETAMOUNT
,e.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR
,YEAR(BILLDATE) AS DATEYEAR
, MONTH (BILLDATE) DATEMONTH 
FROM syncbill a 
INNER JOIN ecustomer e ON a.OUTLET=e.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER  
    and YEAR(BILLDATE) = '2018' AND MONTH(BILLDATE) = '09' 
group by outlet

UNION ALL

SELECT sum(a.netamount) NETAMOUNT
,e.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR,
YEAR(BILLDATE) AS DATEYEAR
, MONTH (BILLDATE) DATEMONTH 
FROM syncbill a
INNER JOIN ecustomer e ON  a.OUTLET=e.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER 
    and YEAR(BILLDATE) = '2018-1' AND MONTH(BILLDATE) = '09' 
group by outlet
```

If you want two separated  rows  you could use union all

UNION ALL return always both the row result

You could also use a single query group by year

```
    SELECT sum(a.netamount) NETAMOUNT
    ,e.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR
    ,YEAR(BILLDATE) AS DATEYEAR
    , MONTH (BILLDATE) DATEMONTH 
    FROM syncbill a 
    INNER JOIN ecustomer e ON a.OUTLET=e.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER  
        and YEAR(BILLDATE) IN ('2018', '2018-1') AND MONTH(BILLDATE) = '09' 
    group by outlet, DATEYEAR, DATEMONTH
```

Comment: getting wrong result for 2018 and 2017 it is giving same net amount

Comment: asnwer updated ..usinh UNION all you obtain both the result

Comment: my second query have empty value i wan't to validate that if no data is in 2017 then it should give net amount as 0 outlet/customerdiscriptor as the same for 2018 and year should be 2017

Comment: you comment is not clear  ..  you just asked  for "join "  two query  .. this is not related  to the content ..  of your data  .. .SO is not  a free coding service ..but an question/answer  site ..

Comment: yup i know sir its not free coding service,but getting confused

Comment: I can't know what you  have in your data ..  and as in previous comment  .. you comment is not clear .. .. the two query return values if these values exisit ..  if you want select or not  a value ..have not sense to  me    ..

Comment: @viveksingh   .. i have added  also another solution based on group by year too  .. could be this is usefult too